# How to put a class attribute into a field with xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to change from this output

```
<Event>
    <eventState class="scientificEvents.state.EventRegistered">
        <event reference="../.."/>
    </eventState>
</Event>
```

to this output

```
<Event>
    <eventState>scientificEvents.state.EventRegistered</eventState>
</Event>
```

Have been looking everywhere for this and can't find anything! Only adding fields as attributes which is not what I'm looking for

Here are my classes

```
public class Event{
    private EventState eventState;
}
```

EventState

```
public interface EventState{}
```

Class that implements EventState

```
public abstract class EventStateImpl implements EventState
{
   private Event event;

   public EventStateImpl(Event e)
       {
        event = e;
       }
 }
```

Set this classe as a state of the event

```
public class EventRegistered extends EventStateImpl
{
    public EventRegistered(Event e)
    {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

Basically the event holds a class in its attribute and I want to put it as a field in xml output. This is what I'm doing at the moment

```
File file = new File("events.xml");
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
Event event=new Event();
event.setState(new EventRegistered());
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file)
String xml = xstream.toXML(events);
out.write(xml);
out.close();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as a sidenote and maybe slightly off-topic: You could [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) instead of xstream and avoid external dependencies.

Comment: JAXB requires annotations, otherwise, the code gets too long and confusing. It is a mess if I want to save objects from an API